# accessing the values of 2 submit button with the same name using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit

I have two submit buttons with the same name but submitting different values in my html form, how can know which submit button was pressed when any one of them is pressed using javascript...?
like,

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="2" />
```

Comment: In your click event handler use `this.value` and see if it's `1` or `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use jquery you just can try using onclick event:

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="1" onclick="showValue(this)"/>
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="2" onclick="showValue(this)"/>
```

Then in javascript:

```
function showValue(obj) {
   alert(obj.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them different ids and check for the id with

```
 this.id;
```

Comment: Could you please tell how can i check for the id of the clicked button..?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this could be like this:

First set the same class for both buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="1" class="myclass"/>
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="2" class="myclass"/>
```

Then in javascript:

```
$("input .myclass").click(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: the code you have given is jQuery, can you give a javascript code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

One not very elegant solution - but still one possibility - is to use a hidden and two or any quantity of button-type inputs.

configure onclick to set the hidden and then submit the form.

```
<form id="f1">
   <input type="button" onclick="setAndSubmit(1)" value="send 1" /> 
   <input type="button" onclick="setAndSubmit(2)" value="send 2" /> 
   <input type="hidden" name="fakebutton" id="fakebutton"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAndSubmit(n){
       $('#fakebutton').val(n);
       $('#f1').submit();
    }
}
```